# Chrome extension detect user added new tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a situation where the user reboots his/her pc without closing chrome, the tabs will automatically return when chrome is being re-opened.

What I want to know is how to distinguish that the user opened a new tab.

I have the following function:

```
const interceptRequests = () => {
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    async details => {
      if (requestIsUserInitiated(details)) {
        const tabs = await getAllTabs();
        console.log('get all the tabs', tabs);
        console.log('details', details);
      }
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking"]
  );

};
```

Where:

```
const requestIsUserInitiated = details =>
  details.type === 'main_frame'
    && !details.initiator // ignoring requests made by the website
    && details.method === 'GET';
```

The thing is, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to distinguish whether the browser initiated the request, or the user, unless there is a property that I'm not seeing:

[image]
[image]

Of course there is the following listener:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {         
});
```

However, when Chrome opens all the tabs, then it will probably get triggered anyway.

So how can one make the distinction? I want to trigger a function when it is certain that the user initiated the new tab to make the request.

Comment: You wrote "`it will probably get triggered`", so you did not try it first?

Comment: @ahwayakchih I'm at work and cannot afford to reboot my pc for every test here.

Comment: Doesn't Chrome reopen tabs after its processes are killed from your system's process manager?

Comment: Anyway, you could maybe store number of tabs opened, so next time browser starts, you could skip that number of tabs, but that's error prone i guess. You could also just wait a second or two after extension is initialized, so Chrome would re-open tabs in meantime, but that's too a bit too fragile solution.

Comment: Try setting a global "ok" flag in chrome.runtime.onStartup listener that you'll check in other listeners.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, will check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { interceptRequests } from './requestInterceptor/index';
import { cleanTabs } from './tabCleaner/index';

let extensionIsInitialized = false;

const startBackgroundProcess = () => {
  if (! extensionIsInitialized) {
    interceptRequests();
    cleanTabs();
    extensionIsInitialized = true;
  }
};

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(startBackgroundProcess);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(startBackgroundProcess);
```